git --format="%(decorate)" not recognized?
The pretty-format specifier "%(decorate)" is not recognized in git 2.42.0. Is this is no longer supported, or was it never supported, or am I using it incorrectly?
$ git log --format="%h foo %(decorate)" -1
9b204ca2e2 foo %(decorate)


It worked for me with 2.43.0

Yep.. it seems to have shown up in 2.43: https://github.blog/open-source/git/highlights-from-git-2-43/

Try %d instead of %(decorate).

Aw nuts, thanks! Upgraded and all is well.
fwiw I'm using $(decorate:prefix=%n,suffix=) so that the refs will be printed on their own line, without parens.
